PowerShell script to detect whether the user has enabled screen lock password for Windows is not giving constant result on every run
I have this Powershell script to check whether the user has enabled lock screen password for their Windows system. It is giving the expected result mostly. But on some iterations it is showing the below error.
my script
Add - Type - AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement $PrincipalContext = New - Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext('Machine')

try {
  Get - LocalUser | Where - Object Enabled - eq $true | ForEach - Object {
    $localUsers = $_.Name $isPasswordNull = $PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials($localUsers, $null, [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions]'Negotiate') If($isPasswordNull) {
      Write - Host "User have no password"
      break
    }
  }
  write - host "All user has password"
} catch {
  Write - Host $Error[0]
} finally {
  $PrincipalContext.Dispose()
}


The error I'm getting sometimes:
Exception calling "ValidateCredentials" with "3" argument(s): "The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to. "
I'm using this in my electron app, and it is observed with Windows 10 and 11 all versions. Mostly it is working fine but recently it started showing the error often.
Any suggestions on modifying the code / do I need to change anything in Windows settings?

further points: This script is running when the user is logged in . and there is only one user account associated with that computer.

Is there any chance that the user's account is actually locked out when you get the errors?  Where I work, we have at times issues where users can't access resources because someone, typically in some other country, was trying to hack their account.

no i am checking this in real time. i dont understand what this locked out implies when im executing this script on the same computer. if it is locked out i should see the lock screen to enter password i believe. im operating on the computer in this case wondering what this exception is

I'm assuming you have a computer on the domain, and the account you are logged in is a domain account.  As such, if a user tries to log in too many times, failing to put the correct password in each time, the account becomes locked.  If the user's phone has the wrong password for the wireless network, user's account gets locked.  If a hacker pretends to be the user, fails multiple times to gain access, the account is locked.  Users lose access to network drives, email, and anything that requires authentication, typically for 15 minutes until account is unlocked again.

It doesn't matter if the user is already logged in to the local computer, if something causes their account to be locked at the domain level, they lose access to everything that requires authentication.
